# Creating a local server in android

Tags: android

I want to create an app that can send and receive files like text and images between multiple users in android without any net connections. Just to create a local server in one device and use it as a hotspot for transmission of data.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using socket programming.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/

In nut shell, The device which you would like to make as server should create a server socket and continue listening to a port. All client devices can create a client socket and connect to the server socket and transmit data.

You can refer to the sample app "Bluetooth Chat" which is available with Android sdk sample. You can use the same concept to transfer files as chunks of bytes (part by part).

Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Start with basics
   (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communications_protocol)
2. Think about what you want to achieve.
3. Choose your protocol or technology (HTTP, FTP, REST, UPnP or
   thousand-others)
4. Then move on to implementation. You are likely to use some existing library.